# Trying to use python on a server

Tags: python, tweepy

I am using pythonanywhere.com and trying to run an app that I made for twitter that uses tweepy but it keeps saying connection refused or failed to send request. Is there any way to run a python app online easily that sends requests?

Comment: do you have a premium account? (i.e. anything paid)

Comment: nope i have a free account @RonE

Answer (score 0):

Pythonanywhere requires a premium account for web access.

You can create a limited account with one web app at your-username.pythonanywhere.com, **restricted Internet access from your apps**, low CPU/bandwidth. It works and it's a great way to get started!

Get a premium account:
$5/month
Run your Python code in the cloud from one web app and the console
A Python IDE in your browser with unlimited Python/bash consoles
One web app with free SSL at
your-username.pythonanywhere.com
Enough power to run a typical 50,000 hit/day website.
(more info)
3,000 CPU-seconds per day
(more info)
512MB disk space

---

That said, I'd just set it up locally if its for personal use and go from there.

Comment: thanks for your response. I actually have a few apps (not apps but like bash console stuff kind of) that I need to run and 24/7 and the reason I wanted to do it online is because sometimes I have to shut my laptop and it would be easier to just have it run online all the time and i wouldn't have to think about it

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here -- internet access from free accounts is restricted, but we do specifically whitelist the Twitter API, so it *should* work.  Could you go into more detail about what errors you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a server that has a public IP.

You have a few options here:

1. You can use a platform-as-a-service provider like Heroku or AWS Elastic Beanstalk.
2. You can get a server online on AWS, install your dependencies and use it instead.

As long as you keep your usage low, you can stay withing the free quotas for these services.